# find $f(x)$ and its domain given $f(x+\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: functions

We know that :
$$ f(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 5$$

How we can find $f(x)$ and its domain ?

My try : I assumed $x + \frac{1}{x} = t$  , but I was unable to solve it .

Comment: Fact is that, since the function $x\mapsto x+\frac1x$ is not surjective, the function $f$ could assume any value outside of the image of the aforementioned function.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Can you explain more ? What is your idea about domain of $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t=x+1/x$

$$f(t)=t^2-2+5=t^2+3$$

**Domain:**

What we have here is a composed function problem.

If we call $g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ the original problem is like $f(g(x))$, where $f(x)=x^2+3$.

For $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:C \rightarrow D$ we should have is $\text{Im}(g) \subset A$, if not, $f(g(x))$ doesn't make sense.

Once nothing is said about $A,B,C,D$ we have to make some assumptions. Some reasonable assumptions would be $C=\Bbb R^*$ and $D= \Bbb R$. Now we can find out the image of $g$.

$$x+\frac{1}{x}=t \Rightarrow x^2-tx+1=0$$

$$x=\frac{t\pm\sqrt{t^2-4}}{2}$$

And once $x \in \Bbb R^*$ then we shoud have $t^2-4\ge0 \Rightarrow t \le -2$ or $t \ge 2$. Now we know that:

$$\text{Im}(g)=(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$$

Asking for a domain is not that precise, because we can choose any domain $A$ such that $\text{Im}(g) \subset A$ and then we have infinite possible domains, including $\text{Im}(g)$ itself.

In order to get a more precise answer, let's make one more assumptions: we can assume that the required domain is the biggest set $A\subset \Bbb R$ such that it cans cover $\text{Im}(g)$. If we do that we can say that the domain for $A$ is $\Bbb R$, and on that case we don't know what happen with the function $f$ outside of $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.

**P.S:** From my experience teaching and solving problems in a high school level, I think the expected answer for the domain is $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$, but of course, if we want to be more precise (math competition level, university level and beyond) we can take $\Bbb R$ as the domain but we also made some assumptions to get that.

Comment: Okay , But what about domain of $f(x)$ ?

Comment: But I think domain is $\Bbb R - \{0\} $.

Comment: That is not true! try to find $x$ for $t=1$

Comment: I think we find domain of main function.

Comment: According to your answer , we can't put $x = 1$ . But we can do it and we get $f(2) = 7$

Comment: take a look : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+f(x%2B1%2Fx)%3Dx%5E2%2B1%2Fx%5E2%2B5

Comment: Nope! You first have to find the expression for $f$. After that you can find your domain. $x=1$ is equivalent to $t=2$.

Comment: @SHW: wolfram is assuming that the domain is $\Bbb R$. That is the domain for the composed function, not for $f$. If that is what you looking for that should be in the statement.

Comment: I'm really confused about domain . We know $f(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 5$. It is obvious that we can't put $x=0$. Am I right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50403/discussion-between-arnaldo-nascimento-and-s-h-w).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] It follows that $f(t)=t^2+3$ for $t$ in the range of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ which is $t \in (-\infty,-2] \cup [2,\infty)$. The function can take any values inside $(-2,2)$, so the general solution is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x^2 + 3 & \quad \quad x \in (-\infty,-2] \cup [2,\infty) \\
\text{arbitrary} & \quad \quad x \in (-2,2)
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Okay , But what about domain of $f(x)$ ?

Comment: It follows from the above that $f(x)=x^2+3$ so the domain is the entire $\mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv: Not quite: what real numbers may be written as $x + \frac 1 x$?

Comment: @AlexM. Point taken, I edited the answer to address that.

Comment: @dxiv I think you must omit $0$ from domain.

Comment: @S.H.W No, why would you think so. $0 \in (-2,2)$ is in the range where the function can take *any* value, and still satisfy the given identity.

Comment: But how can evaluate function for $x = 0$ ?

Comment: Take a look : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+f(x%2B1%2Fx)%3Dx%5E2%2B1%2Fx%5E2%2B5

Comment: @S.H.W Suppose I give you one of many solutions: $$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x^2 + 3 & \quad \quad x \in (-\infty,-2] \cup [2,\infty) \\
0 & \quad \quad x \in (-2,2)
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Can you verify that (a) this function is defined on the entire $\mathbb{R}$, and (b) satisfies the given identity?

Comment: Yes , for example if $x = 0$ then $f(0)  = 0$ . I think if you write $x \in (-2 , 2) - \{0\}$ , your answer is right.

Comment: @S.H.W There is no reason to exclude $0$. Read also Alex M's answer, which makes the very same point: "*What about the interval (−2,2) ? On this interval we may define f in any way we want, because the numbers in it cannot be of the form x+1/x, so the hypothesis in the statement of the problem does not apply to them.*".

Comment: @dxiv According to your answer domain of $f(x)$ is Real numbers but I'm still confused about relation of $f(x)$ . Why if $x \in (-2,2)$ , value of $f(x)$ arbitrary ?

Comment: @S.H.W Since $x+\frac{1}{x} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus (-2,2)$ the given relation can not define the behavior of $f$ in $(-2,2)$, so $f$ can take any values in that interval. I explained that several times already, and I don't know how to explain it any better. Maybe it helps to look at it the other way around: I gave an explicit example of such an $f(x)$ a couple of comments earlier. If you believe that $f(x)$ is *not* a solution to the original problem, find an $x$ where the relation is *not* satisfied. If you can't find one (because none exists) then the respective $f(x)$ *is* a solution.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$x^2 + \frac 1 {x^2} + 5 = x^2 + 2 + \frac 1 {x^2} + 3 = \left( x + \frac 1 x \right) ^2 + 3 ,$$

so

$$f \left( x + \frac 1 x \right) = \left( x + \frac 1 x \right)^2 + 3 .$$

If we want to replace $x + \frac 1 x$ by $t$ and write that $f(t) = t^2 + 3$, then we have to find all those real $t$ with this property.

If $|t| \ge 2$, then the equation $x + \frac 1 x = t$ can be rewritten as $x^2 - tx + 1 = 0$, which has the discriminant $t^2 - 4 \ge 0$, so the equation has real roots. If $|t| < 0$ then there is no real $x$ such that $x + \frac 1 x + t$.

This analysis allows us to say that for $t \in (-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$ we have $f(t) = t^2 + 3$.

What about the interval $(-2,2)$? On this interval we may define $f$ in any way we want, because the numbers in it cannot be of the form $x + \frac 1 x$, so the hypothesis in the statement of the problem does not apply to them.

To conclude,

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} t^2 + 3, & t \le -2 \\
\text{anything}, & t \in (-2, 2) \\
t^2 + 3, & t \ge 2 , \end{cases} $$

and the domain of definition is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you explain to me what will happen if we put $x = 0$ ?

Comment: @dxiv I'm really confused about domain . We know $f(x+\frac{1}{x}) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 5$. It is obvious that we can't put $x=0$. Am I right ?

Comment: @S.H.W The given relation does not apply to $x=0$ but this does not mean that $f(0)$ must not exist. It only means that the value of $f$ at $t=0$ can not be derived from the given relation.

Comment: Okay , Therefore you must omit one number from domain.

Comment: @S.H.W No. Consider for example that the value at $t=1$ can not be derived from the relation, either, since there is no real $x$ such that $x + \frac{1}{x} = 1$. Would that be a reason to eliminate $t=1$ from the domain? Obviously no, and the exact same argument applies to $t=0$.

Comment: @S.H.W: If you put $x=0$, what do you do with $\frac 1 x = \frac 1 0$?

Comment: It is not defined.

Comment: @Alex M. What is your mean by "anything" ?

Comment: @S.H.W: $\text{anything}$ means any function defined on $(-2,2)$. By the way, you have accepted an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Alex M. I think it is complete answer now.

Comment: @S.H.W: It is, but out of 4 answers currently on this page, 3 were initially mistaken and needed edits to become complete. Not good.